# WSSE (with digest) in WCF\.Net\C# - An easy way?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services

**Disclaimer: .Net N00b**

I've been beating my head against the wall for a couple of days now trying to get the security work with this external vendors web service to no avail. It turns out that they use WSSE digest security, which, in short, adds something like this to the SOAP header:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Example-1"> 
   <wsse:Username> ... </wsse:Username> 
   <wsse:Password Type="..."> ... </wsse:Password> 
   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="..."> ... </wsse:Nonce> 
   <wsu:Created> ... </wsu:Created> 
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

I started out by adding the service reference, and through many, many blog posts, stackoverflow questions fiddling with the app.config and the code. I just couldn't seem to get it right. Maybe it isn't easily possible? Maybe I just don't know Visual Studio 2010 and .Net that well, I'm not sure.

Here is what I stopped with in my app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServiceHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://vendorurl"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceHttpBinding"
          contract="ContractName"
          name="ServiceHttpPort">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And the C#:

```
    var someService = new ServiceClient();

    someService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    someService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "passwordgobbletygook/somemorebase64stuff=";

    #region Begin Magic
    var elements = someService.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();

    var securityBindingElement = elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>();
    securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;

    someService.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
    #endregion

    var response = someService.webMethod(param1, param2, param3, param4);

    Console.WriteLine(response);
```

The funny thing is, in the vendors spec, I found that they encourage the use of WSSJ, so I tried it out (in java) and **I GOT IT TO WORK IN 2 HOURS**

Here is what that looks like:

```
public class Test implements CallbackHandler {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Throwable {
        SomeService_Service someService_Service = new SomeService_Service();
        SomeService someService = someService_Service.getSomeServiceHttpPort();

        BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)someService;
        Map< String, Object > requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put( BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://vendorurl" );

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient( someService );
        Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();

        Map< String, Object > outProps = new HashMap< String, Object >();
        outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN );
        outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.USER, "username" );
        outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_DIGEST );
        outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, new Test() );

        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor( outProps );
        endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add( wssOut );

        System.out.println( someService.webMethod(param1, param2, param3, param4) );
    }

    public void handle( final Callback[] callbacks ) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[ 0 ];

        // set the password for our message.
        pc.setPassword( "passwordgobbletygook/somemorebase64stuff=" );
    }
}
```

Has anyone out there in stackoverflow land got this to work in .Net\C#? Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: I've never gotten WS-Security to work for interop with non-.Net languages.  We developed a web service last year and our Java partner could not properly connect during weeks of experiments until we finally just switched to Basic Auth over HTTPS :S.  I get the feeling the spec for WS-Security was just a little to idealistic for practical use.

Comment: Interesting comment @mellamokb. I was able to get it to work with java just fine, it is the .Net code I could not get to work. This particular vendor (Taleo) interops with many other software clients, and this is what they use for security, so someone out there must have got it to work.

Comment: Let me clarify what I meant. I meant interop between .Net and non-.Net language.  Java-to-Java works beautifully as we discovered, and so does .Net-to-.Net.  But when we tried .Net-to-Java, we encountered all sorts of obscure errors and conditions and got way in over are heads until we gave up on it.  Not saying it's impossible, but I just remember a strong pain point with that project.  I'll be interested to know how you get it to work.  I'm am a bit of a web services n00b myself, so that may be part of it :)

Comment: @mellamokb - I'm not sure what the server side is, but I suspect that it is java, so that may be it.

Answer (score 6):

We've run into this problem before when trying to connect a .NET based component to a JAVA based SOAP service. Our solution doesn't involve any XML construction and is IMHO a bit cleaner than anything else I've seen.

The downside is that you need to download and include an older optional .NET DLL to make it work. The upside is that the code is quite clean and fits naturally into WCF.

The basic implementation looks something like this:

```
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    //Class from WSE 3.0
    UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("MY_USERNAME", "MY_PASSWORD", PasswordOption.SendHashed);

    //Add Auth to SOAP Header
    MessageHeader header
      = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
      "Security",
      "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
      token.GetXml(new XmlDocument())
    );

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

    //Build Request
    OrgWS.OrganizationDetailsRequest request = new OrgWS.OrganizationDetailsRequest()
    {
        ID = 1
    };

    //Send Request
    OrgWS.OrganizationDetail[] response = client.getOrganizationDetail(request);

    //Do something with response
}
```

A full explanation can be found here: http://cxdeveloper.com/article/implementing-ws-security-digest-password-nonce-net-40-wcf

Comment: This is the nicest cleanest solution i found while scurrying the web for an answer.
This answer really needs to get more appreciation!

Comment: Alternatively you can create your proxy using the legacy web reference .NET 2.0 method, add the WSE dll to your project, and then manually change the base class in your proxy to the Microsoft.Web.Services3 class.

Answer (score 0):

Andy's answer is spot on! Spent most of the say on this, there is a lot out there but this is the ONLY answer that worked for me. Perfect for adding nonce with passwordDigest in SOAP wsse headers. Agree with Nick V, this answer should get more recognition.

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("****");
WebServiceServiceClient cc = new WebServiceServiceClient(myBinding, ea);

cc.Open();

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(cc.InnerChannel))
{
    //Class from WSE 3.0
    UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("userid", "password", PasswordOption.SendHashed);

    //Add Auth to SOAP Header
    MessageHeader header
      = MessageHeader.CreateHeader(
      "Security",
      "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
      token.GetXml(new XmlDocument())
    );

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

    try
    {
        //call SOAP methos
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //catch any errors
    }
}
```